# Entity Framework Error, One table always getting timeout

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

I have following code to get a particular user details from DB, from 5 different tables.

```
var userValues = usrRepository.AsQueryable()
    .Where(user => user.UserType == (int)GlobalEnumeration.UserType.MDappUser && user.IsActive == true)
    .Include(f => f.appusraddrs)
    .Include(c => c.usrcalendar)
    .Include(f => f.usrattributes)
    .Include("usrAttributes.usrAttributeValues")
    .Include("usrAttributes.usrAttributeValues.ApplicationAttributeValue")
    .ToList();
```

However I always get the Timeout error when ever I try to include the table `ApplicationAttributeValue` using the last include `.Include("usrAttributes.usrAttributeValues.ApplicationAttributeValue")`.

If I do not include that table, I do not get an error.

**Error Stack**

```
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding. ---> System.TimeoutException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
at MySql.Data.Common.MyNetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at MySql.Data.Common.MyNetworkStream.HandleOrRethrowException(Exception e)
at MySql.Data.Common.MyNetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.TimedStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
at System.IO.BufferedStream.Read(Byte[] array, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.ReadFully(Stream stream, Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.LoadPacket()
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.ReadPacket()
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.GetResult(Int32& affectedRow, Int64& insertedId)
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.NextResult(Int32 statementId, Boolean force)
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.NextResult()
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.ExceptionInterceptor.Throw(Exception exception)
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.HandleTimeoutOrThreadAbort(Exception ex)
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
at MySql.Data.Entity.EFMySqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityCommandDefinition.ExecuteStoreCommands(EntityCommand entityCommand, CommandBehavior behavior)
```

And

```
at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityCommandDefinition.ExecuteStoreCommands(EntityCommand entityCommand, CommandBehavior behavior)
at System.Data.Objects.Internal.ObjectQueryExecutionPlan.Execute[TResultType](ObjectContext context, ObjectParameterCollection parameterValues)
at System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)
at System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator()
at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
at MyBusiness.Business.SearchIndexing.SearchIndexBC.GetMyBusinessDetails()
at MyBusiness.Framework.Indexing.Services.IndexingTaskExecutor.BatchIndex(String indexName, String settingsFilename, IndexSettings indexSettings)
at MyBusiness.Framework.Indexing.Services.IndexingTaskExecutor.UpdateIndexBatch(String indexName)
at MyBusiness.Business.ProfileManagement.ProfileManagementBC.UpdateOtherDetails(appuser user)
```

Comment: What *exactly* is `usrRepository`? What is its type? If you *need* `AsQueryable`, that makes me nervous... Have you looked at the generated SQL? How much data do you have?

Comment: Dear Jon it is a repository, appuserRepository userRepository = new appuserRepository(unitOfWork); Where appuserRepository is Repository of type appuser entity

Comment: So does it not implement `IQueryable<T>` already?

Comment: So why the call to `AsQueryable`? I suggest you remove it unless you really need it...

Comment: Sorry I am getting difficulty in forming the query without AsQueryable() as I am not that good in Linq. I think it should start with var userValues = usrRepository.GetAll()? not sure.

Comment: Well if the repository implements `IQueryable<T>` itself, you shouldn't need anything else. Anyway, that's probably not related to your problem - it's worth making sure you understand everything about how your repository is meant to be used though.

Comment: Thanks Jon, It got solved by adding timeout for Context. And as you suggested I removed `AsQueryable()`. Thanks for helping out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got solved by extending timeout for `ObjectContext`by adding `((IObjectContextAdapter)this.context).ObjectContext.CommandTimeout = 180;`

Comment: The problem is not the timeout length, the problem is why it get the timeout?